# Why use `AS` in MySQL queries instead of writing the name of the table?

Tags: mysql

What is gained when writing:

```
SELECT m.`iD` FROM `MyTable` AS m
```

instead of:

```
SELECT `MyTable`.`iD` FROM `MyTable`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose would be to change the name of a column to the "AS" name for subsequent result set processing.  Suppose you have a function that reads a result set and expects a column named "FOO", but your table has the column named "BAR".

If you write:

```
SELECT bar from MYTABLE;
```

The result set will have a column named "bar".  If you write:

```
SELECT bar from MYTABLE as foo;
```

Then, the result set will have a "foo" column.  It allows you to alias a column name.

Answer (score 4):

Either form is acceptable.  Sometimes you do it just to reduce the amount of typing.  Sometimes it is necessary, for instance when joining a table with itself.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, not much, however in larger queries it's significantly faster, easier and more concise to abbreviate table names when typing. Convention has it that one or two letter aliases are preferred.

Comment: I think you are mixing this up with:
    SELECT x FROM SOMETABLE T WHERE T.y blah blah...

AS is a column alias.

Answer (score 3):

It's shorter to write! And sometimes the table names might be cryptic so that you gain a better readability.
Also imaging a join on the same table, then it is necessary to use that.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of table names, it can be easier to read and type (by humans).

The `AS` keyword can also be used to alias column names and, of particular use, functions. This makes it possible to get reasonable temporary column names out of certain queries:

```
SELECT columna + columnb as column_sum
```